# Converting Varchar(200) to YYYY-MM-DD format in Teradata SQL

Tags: sql, date, substring, teradata, teradata-sql-assistant

I have a Varchar like so:

```
23FEB2025
```

I am trying to convert it into a format like:

```
1994-02-23 or YYYY-MM-DD
```

I have tried `select cast ('23FEB2025' as date format 'yyyy-mm-dd');` and `sel convert(date,'23FEB2025')`

There are other dates in the column that are formatted like `12DEC65`.
I am now starting to assume that there is no simple way to convert this so I am asking for a little guidance. Would i need to take sub strings of the date and use a bunch of select case statements?

I was hoping to find a short way to do this but it seems there might not be one. I read on here that storing dates as a string is a bad idea and I fully subscribe to that notion now.
Thank you for any help or advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format portion of casting a date is the input format. The output format is based on your locale and date settings.  In your case, you want this:

```
select
cast ('23FEB2025' as date format 'ddMMMYYYY')
```

Which will return 2025-02-23.

Comment: Thank you for correcting that error! The output i get from that is 2/23/2025, i assume it might be a teradata sqla thing if we aren't getting the same output. I assume i would just have to cast again to reverse the order?

Comment: In SQL Assistant, to change the date format - Tools > Options > Data Format.